# Why table header and first left column not scrolling with tbody?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[I was following this codepen](https://codepen.io/MaxArt2501/pen/qLCmE) and have tried to make a similar version [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fw0od1bh/12/)
Even though i am using the same jquery on the classes and have altered css a little to fit my needs. The column and header are not scrolling at all. Please help.

The jquery piece

```
  onload = function() {
  var fcBody = document.querySelector(".fix-column > .tbody"),
  rcBody = document.querySelector(".rest-columns > .tbody"),
  rcHead = document.querySelector(".rest-columns > .thead");
  rcBody.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  fcBody.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  rcHead.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
  });
  };
```

Comment: you are using javascript not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the onload function. its better to use document ready function of jquery if you can prefer.

```
jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/fw0od1bh/15/
```

fiddle has been updated

Comment: is it possible to fix the last column also in the same?

Comment: like first column ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.rest-columns {
   width: 40%;
   overflow: auto;
   float: left;
}
```

[fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/fw0od1bh/14/)